# I'm trying to run a program I converted from .py to exe but it's giving me the error "failed to execute script 'filename'."

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

The script I wrote is very simple and does not require any external files for it to work. I also tested it before converting it to an executable file and it ran as expected. Pyinstaller is how I converted it.

This is the code

```py
# Imports
from shutdown import *

def initiate_shutdown():
    """Activate the program by using this singular function"""

    # Main code
    shutdown(force=True, warning_off=False)

# Exectutes it
initiate_shutdown()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
# Executes it    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    initiate_shutdown()
```